# multi point crossover

Tags: optimization

I try to understand how to write multi-point crossover with NumPy. For example, I have two arrays like

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

And N points

```
np.array([3, 2, 3])
```

The answer should  be like

```
0 1 7 6 5 5 6 7 8 0
9 8 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 9
```

I figured out how it will be for two points

```
def two_point(a, b, point_1, point_2):
   for i in range(point_1+1, point_2):
        a[i], b[i] = b[i], a[i]
    return a, b
```

But I have trouble with n points

Comment: Without code, what whould you expect with more then 2 lists ?How do you swap the items , in which order ?

Comment: Also your method swaps for a range of value, and your expected output sawp only given items, why ?

Comment: I always have two array, I've just created mothod if I have only two points and want to distribute it for several (more then two) points. I do task about Genetic Algorithm.

Comment: Your `two_points` method doesn't do what you need so **figured out how it will be for two points** is wrong ;), check my answer

Comment: thanks, I know that method for two points doesn't work for k points, that's why I'm writing here) Your ansver is not correct (check exmple). Points between each even pair of points are swapped. thank you very much for trying to help me

Comment: I've editer my answer, should be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wasn't easy to find the correct way for the different condition but here you are

```
def swap(vals1, vals2, swap_idxs):
    swap_on = False
    for i in range(len(vals1)):
        if swap_on:
            if i in swap_idxs:
                swap_on = False
            else:
                vals1[i], vals2[i] = vals2[i], vals1[i]
        elif not swap_on and i in swap_idxs:
            swap_on = True

    return vals1, vals2
```

---

When running it

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])

swap_idx = np.array([1, 5, 8])
print(a, b, sep="\n")

a, b = swap(a, b, swap_idx)
print("     | | |         |", a, b, sep="\n")


[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0]
     | | |         |
[0 1 7 6 5 5 6 7 8 0]
[9 8 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution (which seems slightly faster)

```py
def swap(arr1, arr2, n):
    # define n points for crossover (exclude 0 and -1 to really obtain n+1 chunks)
    idx = np.zeros(shape=n + 2, dtype=int)
    idx[-1] = len(arr1)
    idx[1:-1] = sorted(random.sample(range(1, len(arr1) - 1), n))
    # get slices corresponding to odd intervals
    idx_slices = []
    for i, _ in enumerate(idx[:-1]):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            idx_slices.append(np.r_[idx[i] : idx[i + 1]])
    idx_slices = np.hstack(idx_slices)
    temp = arr1[idx_slices].copy()
    arr1[idx_slices] = arr2[idx_slices]
    arr2[idx_slices] = temp
```